# MongoDB import giving an error

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to import a json file data in mongodb using mongoimport command but its throwing me an error

Error Message: E Query [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14

[Json File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1otHm5EHW1vS3pJSkZNUkJsWWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you paste the error message text please?

Comment: As @IsaacBok mentioned, please edit this question and add the relevant part of the error message. And you've also linked twice to "patient.json".

Comment: The error message is "E Query [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14"

Comment: You cannot load arbitrary json with mongoimport. That expects json that is produced with mongodump. aka exported from mongo. To load data you will need to insert it with another tool, or better, write your own loader that inserts the records.